# Use tracelistener reference that is referenced from another project reference

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5, tracelistener

I have a project structure where we have a referenced project (referred herin as RefProject) which does our logging.  So I call a method in that RefProject and it does a WriteLog call to Enterprise Library and everything works fine with existing Enterprise Library tracelisteners.  All of the Enterprise library dlls are referenced from within the RefProject project.  Everything works fine, and the configuration is done in the web.config of the web project (herein known as WebProject) (WebProject references RefProject, but does not reference the EntLib dlls).

Here is an example of a standard listener configured in web.config..

```
<add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="C:\Logfiles\logger.log"
        footer="" formatter="Text Formatter" header="" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment"
        rollInterval="Midnight" filter="Verbose" />
```

Now, I've created a custom tracelistener in a seperate logging project (herein known as Logging project).  If WebProject references Logging project then everything works and the tracelistener works as expected.  If RefProject references the Logging project then I get an exception when it tries to write to the log file saying it could not find the type.

Ideally, I don't want all of the client applications to need to hold on to this reference.  I'd like this to be all taken care of by the RefProject.  The RefProject already takes care of this with the other EntLib default listeners.  I don't understand why WebProject needs to have this new project reference to logger, when all of the other EntLib components are referenced directly by RefProject and not by WebProject.

Any ideas?

```
<add listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.CustomTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        databaseConfig="ExceptionsDatabase" writeLogStoredProcName="WriteLog"
        addCategoryStoredProcName="AddCategory" type="Logging.CustomExceptionTrackerTraceListener, GB.Logging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
        traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, Callstack" name="Database Exception Tracking Listener"
        formatter="Text Formatter" filter="Error"/>
```

Comment: Do you have CopyLocal set to True for the Logging reference in RefProject?

Comment: Yes.  It is set to Copy Local already.

Comment: Solved.  Everything was set up correctly, but when I build it wasn't outputting the file to bin correctly.  I just had to delete the folder and do a good old fashion Clean + Rebuild and then everything worked as expected.  Phew :)

Answer (score 0):

Try kill de WebServer process, and Clean and Rebuild our project, and run F5 again.